# Transition Animation without storyboard segue swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to change animation when ViewController navigate to another ViewController. I am using storyboard but I am not creating Segue. Navigation done with storyboardID my code for navigation is:

```
let SB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = SB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StartRecordingView")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Now I want to change transition animation during naivation. I searched lot but all solutions is for segue. Can anyone here help how to change animation.

Comment: which types of animation you apply ?

Comment: which type of animation u try

Comment: my app is designed in landscape there is one menu button on top right side. i wan to navigate viewcontroller to menuviewcontroller with some diffrenet animation not like pushview animation.

Comment: actually i havent tried any animation as i dont know how to change animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by navigation controller delegate to modify behavior when a view controller is pushed or popped from the navigation stack of a UINavigationController object.

```
-navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:
```

**Declaration:**

```
 - (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                      animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                   fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                     toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
```

Refer this link :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:

Example link :https://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app

Comment: I have seen this before posting question but I dont want CircleTransitionAnimator animation and i want to change animation for only one viewcontroller

Comment: You can do it for particular controller.